# mutate() got multiple values for argument 'name'

Tags: python, flask, graphql, mutation

I want to query createThemes to my graphql.
My graphql query is:

```
mutation{
  createTheme(name: "qwe"){
    theme{
      id
    }
  }
}
```

So it errors: `mutate() got multiple values for argument 'name'` Can you solve and explain why its printing such error.

My code below:

```
from models import Theme as ThemeModel, Topic as TopicModel, Article as ArticleModel

    ...

class CreateTheme(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        id = graphene.Int()
        name = graphene.String()

    theme = graphene.Field(lambda: Theme)

    def mutate(self, name):
        theme = ThemeModel(name = name)
        theme.insert()

        return CreateTheme(theme = theme)

    ...

class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    create_theme = CreateTheme.Field()

    ...

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation = Mutation)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Solved]
I changed

```
def mutate(self, name):
```

to this:

```
def mutate(self, info, name):
```

Comment: And if you're like me, I added a `@staticmethod` decorator per PyCharm's suggestion (which also removes the `self` parameter). Removing the `@staticmethod` and adding the `self` parameter back in fixed it for me :\

Comment: @OozeMeister Graphene executes resolvers as staticmethod implicitly so there's no need to add static decorator. You can read: https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/objecttypes/#resolverimplicitstaticmethod

Comment: @SherSanginov, rather it executes the function as an unbound method and explicitly passes the `root` or `parent` parameter. Because this is such a surprising gotcha, I decorate all of my resolvers with `@staticmethod` and then use type annotations to explicitly declare the expected type of that `root`. I've learned a lot in the 2 or so years since I left the comment XD Thanks for the link to the docs!

Answer (score 0):

It's missing **info** parameter.

Info parameter provides two things:

reference to meta information about the execution of the current GraphQL Query (fields, schema, parsed query, etc.)
access to per-request context which can be used to store user authentication, data loader instances or anything else useful for resolving the query.

Source: https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/objecttypes/